# Optimize multiple if else in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to figure out if there is a way to simplify the following code

```
    assault<-"13"
drugs<-"35"
homicide<-"09"
kidnapping<-"10"
sex_offense<-"36"
sex_assault<-"11"
theft<-c("12","22","23","24","28")
crime_data$OffenseType<-ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% assault)==TRUE,"Assault",
                               ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% drugs)==TRUE,"Drugs",
                                      ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% homicide)==TRUE,"Homicide",
                                             ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% kidnapping)==TRUE,"Kidnapping",
                                                    ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% sex_offense)==TRUE,"Sexual Offense",
                                                           ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% sex_assault)==TRUE,"Sexual Assault",
                                                                  ifelse((substr(crime_data$NCIC.CODE,1,2) %in% theft)==TRUE,"Theft","Others")))))))
```

Comment: I find [`case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when) from `dplyr` useful for this.

Comment: It would help to see some or all of `crime_data`.

Comment: The data can be viewed here http://data.torontopolice.on.ca/datasets/mci-2014-to-2017/data?selectedAttribute=Lat

Comment: Use a look-up table and a join. Much easier to read, etc.

Comment: Please post sample data. The data you link to is (a) over 100k rows and (b) doesn't have a column called `NCIC.CODE`. You should post a *small* sample of data that illustrates the problem. 10 rows and 2 columns is plenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the `NCIC.CODE` variable was created as it is not in the original data set, but a `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::case_when`  approach, as was mentioned, would be along the following lines:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

assault<-"13"
drugs<-"35"
homicide<-"09"
kidnapping<-"10"
sex_offense<-"36"
sex_assault<-"11"
theft<-c("12","22","23","24","28")

crime_data <- read_csv(file=file.choose())
crime_data %<>%
  mutate(NCIC.CODE = substr(NCIC.CODE,1,2))
  mutate(OffenseType = case_when(NCIC.CODE %in% assault ~ "Assault",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% homicide ~ "Homicide",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% kidnapping ~ "Kidnapping",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% sex_offense ~ "Sexual Offense",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% sex_assault ~ "Drugs",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% theft ~ "Sexual Assault",
                             NCIC.CODE %in% drugs ~ "Theft",
                             TRUE ~ "Others"
                             ))
```

If you let us know how `NCIC.CODE` was created we may be able to help more.

If you use `dput(head(crime_data, 10))` and post the results it will show some of the data

Comment: Thankyou very much. This does look cleaner for my code.

Comment: If this works for you, can you mark the question as answered please